# Parse XML to database

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I´m parsing an XML file from the web and saving the elements to my database. 
All variables are of the type string to make it easy. 
I can save 5 of 7 fields. When I try to parse down all 7 I only get 80 records, and if I comment the 2 lines that doesn't work I get 17000 records. Does anyone know why it stops at 89 records?

Here is the code:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();

xml.Load("http://www.systembolaget.se/Assortment.aspx?Format=Xml");

XmlNodeList documentNodeList = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/artiklar/artikel");

IList<Systembolaget> whiskies = new List<Systembolaget>();
if (documentNodeList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (XmlNode row in documentNodeList)
    {
        Systembolaget sb = new Systembolaget();

        sb.ArtikelId = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Artikelid").InnerText;
        sb.SaljStart = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Saljstart").InnerText;
        sb.Ursprunglandnamn = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Ursprunglandnamn").InnerText;
        sb.VaruNamn = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Namn").InnerText + " " + row.SelectSingleNode("Namn2").InnerText;
        //sb.Argang = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Argang").InnerText;
        sb.Alkoholhalt = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Alkoholhalt").InnerText;
        sb.Volym = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Volymiml").InnerText;
        sb.Pris = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Prisinklmoms").InnerText;
        /*
        if (row.SelectSingleNode("Varugrupp").InnerText.StartsWith("Whisky"))
        {
            var rowVarugrupp = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Varugrupp").InnerText;
            sb.Varugrupp = rowVarugrupp;
        }*/

        whiskies.Add(sb);

        ISystembolagetRepository sbDao = daoFactory.GetSystembolagetRepository();
        sbDao.SaveOrUpdate(sb);
```

Comment: Does it show any error (exception) when reaches those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Varugrupp>` is missing in the 81st record.  Have you tried using Linq to Xml to read your Xml?  I think it is a little easier to work with:

```
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load("http://www.systembolaget.se/Assortment.aspx?Format=Xml");

        List<Systembolaget> whiskies = new List<Systembolaget>();

        foreach(XElement element in document.Element("artiklar").Elements("artikel"))
        {
            Systembolaget sb = new Systembolaget();

            sb.ArtikelId = element.Element("Artikelid").Value;
            sb.SaljStart = element.Element("Saljstart").Value;
            sb.Ursprunglandnamn = element.Element("Ursprunglandnamn").Value;
            sb.VaruNamn = element.Element("Namn").Value + element.Element("Namn2").Value;
            sb.Argang = element.Element("Argang").Value;
            sb.Alkoholhalt = element.Element("Alkoholhalt").Value;
            sb.Volym = element.Element("Volymiml").Value;
            sb.Pris = element.Element("Prisinklmoms").Value;

            if (element.Element("Varugrupp") != null && element.Element("Varugrupp").Value.StartsWith("Whisky"))
            {
                sb.Varugrupp = element.Element("Varugrupp").Value;
            }

            whiskies.Add(sb);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get 80 records by commenting out that IF block that means your 81th record in xml is offending record. Most probably xml node with name "Varugrupp" doesn't exists or you have misspelled it in xpath. Also remember xpaths are case sensitive.
Following statement may be yielding null hence it may be throwing exception.

```
row.SelectSingleNode("Varugrupp")
```

You can get around it by changing if condition as below

```
if (row.SelectSingleNode("Varugrupp")!=null && row.SelectSingleNode("Varugrupp").InnerText.StartsWith("Whisky"))
{
   var rowVarugrupp = (string)row.SelectSingleNode("Varugrupp").InnerText;
   sb.Varugrupp = rowVarugrupp;
}
```